# Why is application domain name is not updated with local bind server in OpenShift Origin, but is available in Route53?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I am new to OpenShift. Currently I have an all in one instance in AWS, and did the install using oo-install utility `sh <(curl -s https://install.openshift.com/)`

When it asked me

```
Do you want to register DNS entries for your OpenShift hosts with the
same OpenShift DNS service that will be managing DNS records for the
hosted applications? (y/n/q)
```

I had answered with `y`.

When I created a new application, it asked me for the domain under which application should be created. Post creation it was updated with the local dns server (local to aws), so I when do a nslookup, it points to local address.

Then to make it visible on Internet, I made an A record entry in Route53 Hosted zone so that my domain points to server where OpenShift is installed, and a CNAME entry for application under that domain. Then I configured Route53 plugin for OpenShift and restarted the server.

Now when I create a new application, it gets created and accessible from Internet, but nslookup from the OpenShift server fails. **Because of this my 1st Application cannot make requests to my 2nd Application using its URL** . Do I need to uninstall the Bind Server or do I need to do something else ?

Thanks

Comment: This is also effecting me with other sites that are hosted on AWS that are trying to access images and the such from my site.